# FSCalendar event dots not showing

Tags: swift, xcode, fscalendar

I am using FSCalendar to render a calendar in my app. At first I used `fillDefaultColorFor` to display the events in color like so:

```
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, fillDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {
    let dateString2 = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
    //set dates with events to yellow
    if self.datesArray.contains(dateString2){

        return UIColor.yellow
    }
    return nil
}
```

But now I want to display events using dots instead using this:

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
   let dateString2 = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)

    print("Dates array at numberOfEvents: ", datesArray)
    print("DateString2: ", dateString2)

    //render dots if there is an event on that day
    if self.datesArray.contains(dateString2){
        return 1
    }else{
      return 0
    }

}
```

However the code above does not render any dots in the calendar. Is there something missing in the `numberOfEvents` method?

EDIT: To test `numberOfEvents` I added an array of dates like so:

```
var testDates = ["2018-09-08", "2018-09-16", "2018-09-20", "2018-09-28"]
```

So the `numberOfEvents` looks like this:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {

  let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
  print("datesArray: ", datesArray)// this is in "yyyy-MM-dd" format
  print("Date String: ", dateString)// displays date in "yyyy-MM-dd" format
  print("testDates: ", testDates)

  if self.datesArray.contains(dateString){
    return 1
  }
  if testDates.contains(dateString){
        return 3
  }

  return 0
}
```

When I run the app there are still no event dots being shown in the calendar. Is there something missing in this code? Some function I missed or implemented incorrectly?

Comment: can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856109/fscalender-events-show-in-swift

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020859/selection-color-changes-the-events-color-in-fscalendar/52170654#52170654

Comment: I've tried to follow like in the code shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020859/selection-color-changes-the-events-color-in-fscalendar/52170654#52170654 but I still can't show just the event dots on the calendar

Answer (score 3):

You have to include **FSCalendarDelegateAppearance** method to show event dots colors and **FSCalendarDataSource** method to give the number of events.

Here's the code

For **FSCalendarDelegateAppearance**

```
extension YourController : FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {

// MARK: - FSCalendarDelegateAppearance

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, eventDefaultColorsFor date: Date) -> [UIColor]? {

    let dateString = date.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd")
    if self.yourDateArr.contains(dateString!) {
        return [UIColor.blue]
    }
    return [UIColor.white]
}
}
```

For **FSCalendarDataSource**

```
extension YourController : FSCalendarDataSource {

// MARK: - FSCalendarDataSource

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {

      let dateString = date.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd")
      if self.yourDateArr.contains(dateString!) {
        return 1
      } 
      return 0
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve my problem with this code:

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, willDisplay cell: FSCalendarCell, for date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    let dateFormatter3 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter3.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let dateString = dateFormatter3.string(from: date)

    //display events as dots
    cell.eventIndicator.isHidden = false
    cell.eventIndicator.color = UIColor.blue

    if self.datesArray.contains(dateString){
        cell.eventIndicator.numberOfEvents = 1
    }
}
```

This should display event dots if there are events on a particular date

Answer (score 0):

Please check your datesArray value also dateArray and date format must be same.

Whichever date event you want to show that date must be in datesArray and also check matching dates strings are in same formate (**yyyy-MM-dd must be**).